# How to display Article's Image in another Container

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, drupal-theming

Every article on my Drupal page has an image. Now I want this image to be a full width stage at the top of the article's page. Is there a way to get the current node's image from within another block or assign the article's image to another block in another region (I have successfully added a full width slider on the front page, so I want to put the image in the same region).

Comment: Question is not very clear. Where do you want to add that image? At top of the article page or in side bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a block view from content, add a contextual filter 'Content: Nid' click on ' Provide default value' option and select 'Content ID from URL'.

On fields section select the image field that you added to your content type.